# Uploading a personal google cloud server into app inventor

Tags: app-inventor

I was reading about creating a custom tinywebdb and wondered will it offer me more entries than the the normal tinywebdb.

I am creating an app using app inventor where users can comment and review about a specific product.

So I was wondering if I create my google cloud, will I be able to upload it into app inventor? If you guys have better advises please tell me!

Answer (score 0):

The limit of 1000 entries is only valid for the default `TinyWebDB` component on the test service provided by App Inventor. For a custom `TinyWebDB` there is no such limit, see also [Creating a Custom TinyWebDB Service](http://ai2.appinventor.mit.edu/reference/other/tinywebdb.html).

You can read here more about [quotas](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas) and [pricing](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/pricing).
See also this [guide for the setup](https://sites.google.com/a/wellesley.edu/wellesley-cs117-fall14/goodies/tinywebdb-services/creating-a-custom-tinywebdb-service) and don't sign up for the free trial.

Generally, as already suggested in the [forum](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mitappinventortest/9cazfD6fwbo/3PrhrZ62QOoJ), I would use a `fusiontable` instead, which offers better filter and query possibilities. Remember, in `TinyWebDB` you can only store tag/value pairs.

Comment: Thank you taifun for your answer. So I should use the fussion table for the users comments? Right?

Comment: yes, and as you are new to Stackoverflow, I recommend you to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) for a quick overview of the site and to read [What does it mean when an answer is "accepted"?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)